# My septic works fine, but I have wet spots

Tags: septic, lawn

So, I have had 2 septic companies inspect our septic system.  One pumped all the water out of the lines and dropped a camera in.  Everything is working perfectly.  We have saturation on our lawn.  So, we still have wet spots near the last leach line of the septic system.  Not sure if it is always grey water or just water from the lawn....it only smells once in a while.  When it is dry and doesn't rain,usually in the summer,  it dries up and no wet spot.  An irrigation company told me a French drain around the perimeter of my back yard would NOT help the issue I have.  Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Are those wet spots in low areas ?

Comment: A lot depends upon the type of soils you have in the area.  Drain fields don't work all that well if you have a fairly high clay content. (Leach fields, in other parts of the country!).  Is your system a pumped system or gravity? If it's a passive gravity system, what you call the "last leach line" might be slightly lower than the other and is therefore doing most of the work.   How many leach fields are there?

Comment: perhaps let your grass grow taller so that it uses more water

Comment: Are those wet spots in low areas ? = Well, yes, sort of...the entire lawn slightly slopes towards the house.  The area where I see water is lower then the back of the lawn...but not a divot or sunken area.

Comment: It is red clay mostly around here (North Carolina). It is a pumped system.  There are 4 lines....the first is at the back of the lawn, then it comes back and has a second line, then comes back and has a third line that actually is a "U" shape...then comes back into the last line.  At the end of this line is where it has trouble drying out...unless it is summertime and hot as crazy.

Comment: Grass taller won't really work where it is....however, I thought about cutting all the trees and bushes that shade the area....that couldn't hurt to give it as much sunlight as possible, right?